# How to determine ftp server filenames encoding?

Tags: ftp, encoding, curlftpfs

I am trying to mount a ftp server with curlftpfc.
But the server has unknown encoding, and all the filenames look like ???????.avi, ??????.inf.

I know that I need to specify the encoding for curlftpfc, but what encoding should I use?
Is there  any simple way to get the encoding used on the server?

Comment: Do you know in what country the server is located, or what is the server software / version?

Comment: Ask FTP server administrator..

Comment: Filenames should be in russian. It is really impossible to ask administrator, otherwise I would definitely do this.

Comment: How to determine FTP server software / version ??

Comment: @Stanpol the server sends that by itself as part of the ftp handshake; you can see it with clients like `ftp` or filezilla

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the filenames are expected to be in russian, the probable encodings include KOI8-R, CP1251 and, more rarely, ISO-8859-5.